# csv file to json keep the date formats as it is

Tags: javascript, xlsx

I want to convert the CSV file to JSON data which contains the same date format as it is.

```
// this is the content of csv file
id,name,date,newdate
1,John,2022-01-01,01/02/2022
2,Mary,2022-02-15,02/02/2022
```

and I want the same date and newdate column without changing date format.

```
fileReader.onload = (e) => {
   const csvData = e.target.result;
   const workbook = XLSX.read(csvData, { type: 'string' });
   const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
   const options = { header: 1, raw: true }; // specify the raw option here
   const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetName], options);
   console.log('data', data);
}
```

Current implementation. and the result is

```
[
    [
        "id",
        "name",
        "date",
        "newdate"
    ],
    [
        1,
        "John",
        44562.22928240741,
        44563.00011574074
    ],
    [
        2,
        "Mary",
        44607.22928240741,
        44594.00011574074
    ],

]
```

Why the date column is converted into numbers? I want the same format string.
I sm using xlsx library import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to try changing the options of

```
const workbook = XLSX.read(csvData, { type: 'string' });
```

to

```
const workbook = XLSX.read(csvData, { type: 'file', raw: true });
```

refer this [link](https://github.com/SheetJS/sheetjs/issues/2812)